# sql query to sum row values in steps of 10

Tags: mysql

i need a query to group users between age groups like 10-20, 20-30, 30-40.

```
users | age

1000    21,
1200    26,
1300    32,
1700    39,
```

is the sample data . is there way in mysql to do this. Any help highly appreciated.

-Avinash

Comment: Have you tried any on your own? What's your best thus far?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean 10-19, 20-29, etc. (no overlapping groups). Something like this might help:

```
SELECT users, age, FLOOR(age/10) AS gp FROM users_table GROUP BY gp
```

You can also use [aggregate functions with GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html) to get group properties.

Answer (score 0):

assume you want to do some aggregation over this group. e.g sum users.

```
SELECT SUM(users), FLOOR(age/10)*10 AS olderThan
FROM t
GROUP BY olderThan
```